# extract a keyword from an URL page source

Tags: html

this keyword is an "**Identified**" tag `<span id="example"> keyword </span>`  . so i want to know which language i could start on in order to make a program that can do this work for me, because I have a lot of URLs to work on and it would take me so much time doing it manually.

Comment: Doing *what* manually?

Comment: going through each URL page source and finding that keyword im looking for by entering : <span id="example"> .
and copy that keyword

Comment: What do you do with that keyword afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

you can use PHP's `preg_match()` to scrap keywords , and to get source code you can use file `file_get_contents()` you have to learn some regex tho

```
$url = 'www.example.com' ;
$WebPage = file_get_contents($url) ;
$Pattren = '/ some regex pattren to capture the right keyword /' ;
preg_match_all($Pattren,$WebPage,$result,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: don't know if that will work but it looks logic, thanks for sharing this information

Comment: it works fine it's called web scraping , i am using it on my website